# Apply styles based on the HTML range input values (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the values from the HTML range input as a CSS selector to apply some styles.

For example, for the given markup,

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" step="1"/>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

the following CSS should apply when the input range slides to value="1",

```css
input[type="range"][value="1"] + p {
   color:red
}
```

The adjacent paragraph should turn red when we slide the range to 1. But it doesn't. However, when I explicitly define the `value` attribute, it works.

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" step="1" value="1"/>
```

It seems that the CSS styles don't update when the range input value is changed by sliding the thumb. Is there a CSS-only solution to make this work?

Comment: No, because the `value` attribute serves only a single purpose: To set the **initial** value declaratively.

Comment: No. `input.onchange` is javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the `value` attribute serves only a single purpose: To set the **initial** value declaratively.

You need a tiny bit of JS here, and modify your CSS to work based off a data attribute:

```css
input[type="range"][data-value="1"] + p {
   color:red
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="2" step="1" oninput="this.dataset.value=this.value" value="0" />
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: I see. So it's more like an initial value rather than the current value. Thanks